# nodejs express app with passport authentication need to use https

Tags: node.js, express, https, passport.js

How can I convert this express server to using https?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = function(passport) {

    /* GET login page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
        res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message') });
    });

    /* GET Registration Page */
    router.get('/signup', function(req, res){
        res.render('register',{message: req.flash('message')});
    });

    return router;
}
```

Comment: This is not the interesting part of the problem. The interesting part is the line where you do the `listen` call of your app. There you have to start it with HTTPS. Your code only shows the routing.

Answer (score 2):

At the minute you'll probably have something that looks like this:

```
app.listen(3000);
```

app.listen is basically an alias for `http.createServer(app).listen(3000)`. *Note:* This may be in `./bin/www` (if you used express-generator).

If you want to have a HTTPS-only server you'll need to replace `app.listen` or `http.createServer()` with the following:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

// ... Express app

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('your/own/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('your/own/cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Thank you Ashley, you point me to the correct file to update :)